# model of two gaussion curves

Tags: r, curve-fitting

How can I create in R a model that contains two Gaussian curves that describe that data I got. So I could get in the end the sigma and median of the Gaussian and calculate which datapoint belongs to which one.

Comment: What do you mean by "a model that contains two Gaussian curves". Do you mean a Gaussian mixture model with two mixture components?

Comment: I do not really know much about this, but I think you are right indeed!

Comment: I have a Python example of fitting a double Lorentzian peak equation to Raman spectroscopy of carbon nanotubes, if that might be of some use.